# Add field and replace its characters with spaces mongodb aggregate

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

I'm trying to search for a record using the record's `name` .

So what i did :

```
let query={}
query.name = req.query.name;

      {
        $match: {
          ...query,
        },
      },
```

it is working fine.

What I'm looking for is to strip some white spaces and letters from the field `name` and replaces it with some letters,  after that search with the new string on `name`

just like using the regular javascript to replace something based on a regex like :

```
let string = 'nice'

string.replace(new RegExp("([\u0622-\u0623-\u0625])"), "oof")
```

is this possible to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [$replaceAll](https://$replaceAll) operator:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "name": "Naruto Uzumaki"
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "name": {
        "$replaceAll": {
          "input": "$name",
          "find": "Naruto",
          "replacement": "Boruto"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Working example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/eppDDLn7b-R)

Comment: but how do you use regex in replacement?